# Custom template for custom post type not recognized by Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type named machines for which I have created a custom template called single-machines.php.

I triple checked the name to make sure it's not a typo.

If I manually set the template to be used it works fine, but Wordpress doesn't recognize it automatically.

How can I make Worpdress recognize it as the template to be used for that post type?

Since I don't know what other factors can play a part in this I would like to add:

- I am working on a child theme.
- I am using the OceanWP theme.
- I have created the post type with PODs.

Comment: You maybe need to go to permalinks page and save it

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. @DessaugesAntoine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/) to show me which template WordPress is currently using, helps when dealing with template hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a child theme, copying the singular.php into it and editing it to show the correct post type for my custom post. It's a workaround, but it works.